# How do I get an Oscillogram for this UPS?

Tags: ups

https://www.cyberpowersystems.com/product/ups/cp1500pfclcd/

I want this unit but after reading this post

[When do I need a pure sine wave UPS?](https://superuser.com/questions/912679/when-do-i-need-a-pure-sine-wave-ups)

Im a bit nervous on spending this much when I don't really know what Im getting. I don't understand enough about power to make an informed decision. Im looking for a ups for a high end gaming pc if that matters.

Comment: What are the specs of your PC? What do you want the UPS do in case of an power outage? Do you want to connect anything else to the UPS (Monitor, ...)? Please edit your answer accordingly and don't reply to this comment.

Comment: You don't.  If you are worried about a $250 UPS, then an to purchase an Oscillogram, to measure the output is way out of your price range.  Even if you have one, if you know nothing about power, you won't even know what you are looking at.  So am entirely confused about what your question actually is.  What problem are you trying to solve exactly?  How you would measure it is simple enough, just requires a cable, but you have to understand what your looking at otherwise it wouldn't mean anything.

Answer (score 2):

As outlined in the [accepted answer](https://superuser.com/a/912689/707676) to the question you linked... you'll probably be fine with a cheap UPS.

The [CP1500PFCLCD](https://www.cyberpowersystems.com/product/ups/cp1500pfclcd/) states that the waveform is "Sine Wave", so you're probably a bit better than fine.

The big thing you should focus on is the power - you state that this is for a "*High-End gaming PC*". Depending on what you actually mean by this, it's possible / likely that the 900W rating will not be enough. (what is your PC's power supply rated for?)

You should never run a UPS over it's rated wattage, even if you are currently "*on mains*" - many will forcibly shutdown in this situation.

---

> How do I get an Oscillogram for this UPS?

By using an [Oscilloscope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oscilloscope) - a piece of electronics lab equipment that allows inspection of analog signals, typically plotted against time. A second hand analog scope can usually be found on eBay for as little as £30.

---

Lastly, please note that hardware recommendations and shopping advice are off topic here.

Comment: Well I settled on this unit based on my power needs with the help of users over on toms forum. I have an i7 7700k gtx 1080 ultra wide monitor, external speakers, a 240gb ssd, and a 1tb hdd. My psu is evga b2 850. The CP1500PFCLCD is 200$ on amazon, and that's the highest va you can get without jumping up a few hundred dollars. At least from what I saw.                    http://www.tomshardware.com/answers/id-3760466/pick-ups.html

Comment: Id also like to add my question is how to get an oscillogram. That can apply to any unit. Any way I got help over on toms as usual, so for anyone interested heres that thread.  http://www.tomshardware.com/answers/id-3766485/oscillogram-ups-havent-bought.html

Comment: I've added a brief section about oscilloscopes to my answer...